# Serialization with a help of reflection of Spring's AbstractBeanDefinition

Tags: java, spring, serialization, reflection

To test [vulnerabilities](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2011-2894) in our system I want to create an [exploit](https://www.div0.sg/single-post/2017/06/17/CVE-2011-2894), which needs to serialize [`GenericBeanDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/GenericBeanDefinition.html) from `spring-beans`.

The super class [`AbstractBeanDefinition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/AbstractBeanDefinition.html) has one attribute which is not serializable: `constructorArgumentValues`.

To hack this I wrote the following code to modify the attribute as `transient` via reflection:

```
// create a bean object
GenericBeanDefinition bean = new GenericBeanDefinition();
bean.setBeanClass(Runtime.class);
bean.setFactoryMethodName("getRuntime");    

// make constructorArgumentValues transient via reflection
try {
    Field field = AbstractBeanDefinition.class.getDeclaredField("constructorArgumentValues");
    Field modifiers = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiers.setAccessible(true);
    modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() | Modifier.TRANSIENT);

    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(bean, null);

} catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

// serialize it
try (FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("test.ser");
     ObjectOutputStream outStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut)) {
    outStream.writeObject(bean);

} catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Unfortunately I get:

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConstructorArgumentValues

The snipplet above works fine, when I try it with another simple class:

```
class MySerializable implements Serializable {
    private MyUnserializable myUnserializable = new MyUnserializable();
}
class MyUnserializable {
}
```

I don't see the problem here. Thanks for any help!

Comment: afaik you cannot change the modifiers without doing bytecode manipulation. But maybe that has changed in a newer java version.

Comment: It works for the simple example, see MySerializable.

Comment: I suspect that that will fail as well if you add add a getter for the `myUnserializable` field returning the value. This will lead to the need to also deserialize the class even if the field is transient.

Comment: I see, you're right. Is there a workaround for this?